# Nested for loop: Storing current screen resolution as a variable for various remote machines using batch script

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, cmd, method-call

I need to get current screen resolution of each remote machines (IPs of the same are stored in .txt file) and store it as a variable in the script to be used further.

I am able to iterate through the machines which are in .txt file and I am able to store the screen resolution as a variable but I am not able to do it in a loop for all the machines.
Can anyone tell where I am going wrong?
How can I use use **%%a** set in first for in the later code and next for loop as well?

```
Set MyFile=VMs.txt
rem VMs.txt contains IPs of the machines

for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("%MyFile%") do call :compare
    
:compare
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%i in ('wmic /node:"%%a" path Win32_VideoController get CurrentVerticalResolution /value ^| find "="') do set height=%%i
echo %height%
```

Comment: I have no idea why you're not using `%__AppDir__%wbem\WMIC.exe /Node:@"VMs.txt" Path Win32_VideoController Get CurrentVerticalResolution /Format:CSV`. Also I'm not sure if you're aware, but if the target machine has dual/multiple graphics cards, each may have a different resolution, and your current methodology would only propagate the variable value with the last listed, not necessarily that which is currently in use.

Comment: Machines can have multiple monitors and all can have a different display resolution.

Comment: I was not aware of this, that opens up a lot of things to explore for me now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to access the `for`-loop meta-variable `%%a` in the called sub-routine `:compare`, which fails. You could:

1. Pass `%%a` as an argument to the sub-routine and access it via `%1` there:

   ```cmd
    Set "MyFile=VMs.txt"
    rem VMs.txt contains IPs of the machines

    for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("%MyFile%") do call :compare %%a
    goto :EOF

    :compare
    for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%i in ('wmic /node:"%~1" path Win32_VideoController get CurrentVerticalResolution /value ^| find "="') do set "height=%%i"
    echo(%height%
   ```

   The `~`-character in `%~1` ensures that the passed argument is unquoted (though this might be unneeded here), so there is exactly one pair of quotes around the expression `"%~1"`.

   Note the command `goto :EOF`, which prevents the code afterwards to become unintentionally executed when the first `for /f` loop has finished.

   Also note the quoted `set` syntax, which protects special characters and avoids unintentional trailing white-spaces.
2. Or ensure that the code in the sub-routine containing `%%a` runs in the body of a `for` loop, because `for` meta-variables are global, but they can only be accessed within `for`-loop context, which does no longer apply in the sub-routine, even though the call comes from a loop body.

   To re-establish the loop context in the sub-routine, just put the relevant code inside of a `for` loop that only iterates once:

   ```cmd
    Set "MyFile=VMs.txt"
    rem VMs.txt contains IPs of the machines

    for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("%MyFile%") do call :compare
    goto :EOF

    :compare
    for %%j in (.) do for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%i in ('wmic /node:"%%a" path Win32_VideoController get CurrentVerticalResolution /value ^| find "="') do set "height=%%i"
    echo(%height%
   ```